# Cannot create a database due to error MySQLConnection' object is not callable

Tags: python, sql, database

I am using `mysql.connector` to connect to my database, but when I try to use the following class declaration and use the connect function (that creates a database and uses it) I get an error of

> TypeError: 'MySQLConnection' object is not callable

Am I doing something wrong while connecting to the database?

```
class database_creator():

    def __init__(self , username , password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password 
        self.cursor = None  # this is the cursor 
        self.connect = None  # this is the cnx the mysql object 
        self.tables = []   # this shows how many databse table are there

    def initializer(self): # sets the cursor and starts the engine 

        self.connect = mysql.connector.connect(user=self.username, password= self.password)
        self.cursor = self.connect.cursor()

    def connect (self , c_database ):
        # c_database is the name of the database that i want to make

            self.cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE(c_database)")


            self.connect.database = c_database #
```

Answer (score 0):

For more information, you could read the [Connector/Python Connection Arguments](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html).

Generally i'd create the DB directly using the sql and only running the sql insertions or queries by using the mysql-connector-python.

However, in your case, the error is probably due to the the bug when you try to execute the database creation sql, you should change it to:

```
def connect (self , c_database ):
    # c_database is the name of the database that i want to make

        self.cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE {}".format(c_database))


        self.connect.database = c_database #
```

But generally, you should try to check if `c_database` you'd like to create exists. if yes, you just assign the `c_database` string; if not, then only you will create the db with the name as `c_database`

```
def createmysqldb(host, port, c_database, user, password):
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host=host, port=port, user=user, password=password)
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    try:
        cnx.database = c_database
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:  # maybe db does not exist
        if err.errno == mysql.connector.errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
            try:
                cursor.execute(
                    "CREATE DATABASE {} DEFAULT CHARACTER SET 'utf8'".format(c_database))
            except mysql.connector.Error as err:
                print("Failed creating database: {}".format(err))
                return
            cnx.database = c_database
        else:
            print(err)
            return
```

Comment: @gghimire, please specify your error tracback. Did you change the line `self.cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE {}".format(c_database))`?

Comment: yes i changed changed the line as mentioned  , but still got the same error message

Comment: @gghimire, please post your full error trackback message